# Coherence Cache invalid schema

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I have this error in my application logs.

Coherence Warning "this document does not refer to any schema definition and has not been validated."

Has anybody seen this before? or Know what is means? It occurs in reference to /my-pof-config.xml

Comment: Two causes I can think of: (1) obvious one - missing DTD reference to `pof-config.dtd`, (2) DTD-reference is present however a custom class loader is used and the jar with DTD cannot be found in the classpath.

Comment: @yegodm care to elaborate?

Comment: @yegodm thanks, let me look into this